# Amazon Echo or Google Home, developer kit capability?

Tags: amazon-echo, google-home

Before buying one of those little awsome object i want to get a simple answer about the allowing capacity with the developer tools.

- Is it allowed to receive the text request in my "skill" or "action"
- Use a bot NPL api like Recast.AI, API.AI, Wit.AI or whatever
- Do anykind of traitement on database
- And finally send a simple text answer to the object

Basically i would like to build bot but im wandering wich kind of restriction they put in the developer kit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure for Google Home but regarding Amazon Echo you can use this hack from [init.ai](https://www.init.ai/), you can follow this tutorial to add custom NLP to your Echo : https://blog.init.ai/alexa-can-you-add-custom-nlp-to-amazon-echo-b743606906f5#.3aim7p72f

Comment: Hey thanks you @plieb i was looking for this kind of answer :) im gonna try it with the Recast.AI API i can be awsome if i am able to write conversation flow with Alexa !